# default value vs. null for foreign key

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, database-design, foreign-keys, default-value

I have a question about using null vs. default value for foreign key columns in database. I found a lot of opposite opinions about null vs. default values when designing databases but not exactly for foreign keys (what are main pros and cons).

Currently I'm designing a new database which will store a lot of data for different web applications and other systems with different data access approaches (ORM, stored procedures) and I want to implement general rules on the lowest level as possible (database). (So not to worry about this rules later in applications).

To give you an example let's say that I have a table of users `User` with foreign key column for his nationality `NationalityID` which is a primary key `CountryID` for table `Country`.

Now I have two/three options:

A: I allow `NationalityID` column (and all other similar foreign key columns in database) to be null and just stick with common approach of checking always and everywhere for null (applying rules in application)

or

B: I assign a default value for every foreign key to be let's say "-1" and put in every relation table additional column with "-1" as a key and all other data as "No data" (for this example in `Country` table I put column with CountryID of "-1" and for `CountryName` I set "No data"). So every time I will want to know users nationality I will always get result without additional code rules (no need for me to check if it's null or not).

or

C: I can disallow null value for foreign keys. But this is really something what I want to avoid. (I need to have an option to store at least basic data (users name) if not the additional data (users nationality))

So is B good approach or not? What am I missing here? Do I lose more that I gain with this approach? Which problems could I have (in addition to be careful to always have additional column in relational tables with ID value of "-1" which says there is "No data")?

What is your good/bad experience with foreign key default values?

thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If you normalize this won't be an issue.**

Instead of putting nationality in the `USER` table, make a `User_Nationality` table that links users to `Country_ID` in the other table.

If they have an entry in that lookup table, great.  If not, you don't need to store a `NULL` or default value for it.

You need to enforce FK relationships, and allowing `NULL` goes against that.  You also don't want to make up information that may not be accurate just to populate a field, which negates the point of requiring the field in the first place.

**Use lookup tables and you can bypass that entirely.**

This will also allow you to change your mind and choose one of your options down the road.

If you use views, you can choose to treat missing data as a `NULL` or a default value without needing to alter the underlying data.

Comment: with lookup tables data will be too fragmented I think. Just for users I will need minimum of 10 lookup tables just for users (there is a lot of different data like Nationality for users which I need to handle). And users is just a small bit of whole database (we need to handle data about work, obligations, activities, security and many more). I will have 100+ tables very quick ...is that the price I need to pay?

Comment: It's the most robust solution.  You will spend a lot of time creating it but once it's in place it will be much easier to maintain.  It will also allow you to add criteria down the road without needing to completely remake your users table.

Comment: How do you then smartly handle problem of multiple records for same user in lookup table? As I mentioned I want general rules applied on lowest, database level. PROBLEM: If I create separate table for storing birth country of an user, for example, I need to apply some additional rule to avoid having person with two birth countries. And also, when I want to insert users birth country I always need to check first if record for birth country already exists and then handle insert or update. Sorry if I gave stupid example, hope you understand what I want to point out:)

Comment: @Janez - Very very very easy - Make a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on your `User_Id` field on the lookup tables.  The DB engine will only allow one row per `user_id` that way.

Comment: I know about constraints and I it looks like its the best solution (at least in my case). I think that I will go ahead with this "look-up table" approach for my database. But now I also need to find I way for database to automatically handle constraints: if someone wants to insert value for user which already exists in lookup table, drop insert for that table and update the existing one instead (triggers maybe?). In that way I will achieve applying global rule on database level (no need to handle it separately in zillion applications on zillion different ways). Thx again...for now:)

Comment: @Janez - you could use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger for that

Comment: "You need to enforce FK relationships, and allowing NULL goes against that." Ummm, WHAT?? nullable FKs are exactly meant for that (enforced optional relationships). Your proposed solution adds complexity and hurts performance.

Comment: +1 for using a separate table but I would not call this a "lookup table". In context, a lookup table would contain all possible domain values that could appear in the `User_Nationality` table, which would probably be a bad idea in this case, nationlaity being a potentially sensitive issue (my father is Cuban and my mother is Icelandic so I am...? :)

Comment: @onedaywhen - Sorry a linking table then :)

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would feel that even if you have a non-entry entry in your database with a key of -1, you would still be performing a check to see whether you want to display 'No Data' or not for each individual field.

I would stick to NULLs.  NULL is meant to mean the absence of data, which is the case here.

Comment: I have a lot of scenarios that returning to me value which says 'No data' will be enough (no additional code, checks needed). Anyway I will use look-up tables approach, thx for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

I like your B solution. Maybe it will be possible to map the values into other entities, so you have Country, and NullCountry that extends Country and is mapped to row with id=-1 and have special code in its methods to make it easy to handle special cases.

One problem is probably that it will be harder to do outer joins on that foreign key.

EDIT: no, there should be no problem with outer joins, because there would be no need to do outer joins.

Answer (score 1):

B is a terrible approach. It is easier to remeber to handle nulls than to have to figure out what magic number you used and then you still have to handle them. Use number 1. But I like JNKs idea best.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest option D. If not all users have a defined nationality then that information doesn't belong in the user table. Create a table called UserNationality keyed on UserId.

Comment: that's  again the look-up tables approach that JNK also suggested. thx